# Multiple Desktops

Tags: windows-7, desktop, multiple-desktop

I want to use more Desktops and  I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium.

So I'm searching for a lightwight programm giving me more space for my icons on the desktop (Like one for video editing, one for games, one for programming and so on) because they don't fit at a single one. All should be at a single monitor.

Do you know of such a tool?

I only found tools resorting the opened applications.

Comment: The SysInternals suite has something called Desktops - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx

Comment: Yes I already found that! But it doesn't provide Seperate Icons. When I delete a icon on the first desktop, it's also deleted on the secound. :(

Comment: Don't they make menus and search for these use cases?

Comment: You can try if VirtuaWin suit your needs: http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: try this tool: http://dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en

Comment: No, VirtuaWin  doesn't provide seperate desktops (icons).

Comment: And Dexpot sadly doesn't either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use Miscrosoft's Sysinternals [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx).  Its extremely lightweight and stable.  I like it over all the other "fancier" virtual desktops out there.

Comment: Yes I already found that! But it doesn't provide Seperate Icons. When I delete a icon on the first desktop, it's also deleted on the secound.

Comment: yes, it does work differently than the other VDs out there, due to how is was programmed.

Comment: No, that's how all of them (that **I** found) work (syncronizing or using the same resource).